# C# Instasharp Help for setup (Instagram API)

Tags: c#, social-networking, instagram

I have been assigned (the whole class) by my teacher to create a GUI for a website(social or commercial)/app ect.. Most have chosen Facebook or Twitter; I have already made those before and my teacher suggested Instagram - I accepted. I then found [Instasharp](http://instasharp.org/) but I didn't find any guide or useful help on Instasharp, to help me get started.

So I would love some help simply setting up the basis for an instagram program (it will not be commercial and only my learning experiance)
I'm just aiming for a feed of images from a certain hashtag/home and a button to be able to 'like' the image, (maybe add a comment).

I have my Instagram Client ID, Client Secret, but I do not understand the use of the Redirect URI and why I need it.

Many Thanks,
-Skye

Comment: I found Instasharp to be very poorly documented and it has some major bug when I try to use the [users.Recent] functions. I had better luck using Skybrud.Social.Instagram.InstagramService. I have code on my github (open source) and you can view my website and my Randomized instagram feed if you wanna hit me up. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI is used during the authentication flow if you need to authenticate a specific user and get an access token. The whole flow is explained in detailed here: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Note that most Instagram endpoint don't need an access token and you can just use your client_id. You will need an access token to like an image on behalf of the user though.

Comment: Thank you for that; but I am unsure about setting up the basis for a program to be able to get images and send 'likes' and comments - if I find out how to do that, I can fill in the rest.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? @BananaVenom